# Applescript save file menu: how to point destination to Desktop?

Tags: applescript

I have an applescript that triggers an export event from Microsoft Outlook. It handles all the dialogs fine except the menu that pops up about where to save the exported .olm file.

I am trying to have it reliably go to the Desktop but instead it goes to whatever folder was last used (to save) in Outlook. I think the menu is ignoring my attempts to set a different destination.

How do I debug this and do it correctly? The relevant lines:

```
set theExportToFolder to "~/Desktop"
tell text field 2 of sheet 1 of window "Export to Archive File (.olm)"
  set value to theExportToFolder
end tell

tell sheet 1 of window "Export to Archive File (.olm)"
  click button "Save"
  delay 0.5
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete example of save as done via GUI scripting (keyboard simulation). In this case it is done for TextEdit (in fact textEdit has a save as Applescript command !). You need to follow same logic for your Outlook Export dialog.

```
tell application "TextEdit" to activate
tell application "System Events" 
    keystroke "s" using {command down} -- save command from menu
    keystroke "my_title" -- fill title of the document in save window
    keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down} -- open goto dialog
    keystroke "/Users/imac27/Desktop/mySamples" -- path from Documents folder
    keystroke return -- close go to dialog with enter key
    keystroke return -- close the save as dialog with enter key
end tell
```

The path to your folder must be adjusted with your users and folder. In this example, the document is saved in folder mySamples on Desktop.

Of course, if your folder to save in is a standard folder like Desktop, Documents,...just use the short key to go directly to that folder: you don't need the go to feature.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dialog box is the standard 'save as...', you can force to go to Desktop by using command/shift/d key which can be done using :

```
keystroke "d" using {command down, shift down}
```

Comment: Excellent, that does work!  What was I doing wrong though - I'd like to know so that I can make it go to any folder I want, not just Desktop.

Comment: replace the "d" by "g" to open the go-to dialog which you can fill with any folder. There are few other shortcuts like that to Home, Documents, Applications Utility folders...

Comment: great, so if I do keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down} , how do I then use the theExportToFolder variable to tell it to go to the folder I want?  I'm trying to test this manually but "g" does nothing in the save dialog when doing it by hand (not via script).

Comment: The short cut command/shift/g works in any save as...dialog. I don't know if Outlook export uses the standard save as... function. if it is, then it must work and you have a pop up dialog asking to enter the path to new folder. you can fill it with a text containing the path. when hit enter, it should be back to usual save as... dialog to fill file name.

Comment: Sorry, how do I "fill it with a text containing the path" - I've got a variable with the path, and "tell text field 2 of sheet 1 of window "Export to Archive File (.olm)"
  set value to theExportToFolder
end tell"  doesn't seem to work.

Comment: After the command/shift/g, new popup window is display, asking the path to the folder. Please check this is the case. If not, it means Outlook does not use standard save as toolbox. if it does, then you can fill the path to folder as follow : It should be format like /Users/my_login/folder. The easiest may be to use keystroke command in a tell "system Event" block.

Comment: Yes, it does open like this!  But it's not working for me to have it fill in the contents of the variable, after the popup appears - I must be doing something wrong. Can you show the full syntax of the "tell system Event" block you suggest? Thank you!!